# Problemas al subir archivo angular a plataforma gitLab

Tags: github, gitlab

ojalá alguien me pueda ayudar.
Estoy tratando de subir un archivo (angular) a la plataforma de gitLab y cada vez que lo hago sube un archivo como este : @5ca0c1b, el cual no me permite abrirlo.
He seguido todos los pasos para subir archivos

git init

git status

git add . (o git add *)

git commit -m "Algún comentario"

git push origin

Comment: Para agregar todos los archivos y subirlos hace git add -A o podes especificar el archivo en caso de ser uno o un directorio. Saludos

Comment: @maximilianoflores al final tenía que borrar el archivo git que se había creado dentro del proyecto